# ASP.NET Members Section - Cannot create and connect to Database

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web, connection-string, website-admin-tool

Visual Studio 2010
MSSQL 2005
Windows Vista

I am creating an ASP.NET website using webforms, I want to create a members section using Web Site Administration Tool. I am following this youtube tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxxFhGF-Z7E) but I am stuck at 2:58 mins into vid.

After I have created users and roles the vid says ASP.NET should automatically create a Database with tables in the APP_Data section in the Solution explorer in ASP.NET. BUT.... mine doesnt create this database. And when I go into  the "Provider" tab in Web Site Administration Tool and test the connection I get an error:

Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

I have looked into lots of solutions online for this but cannot find a solution. Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to run the aspnet_regsql you can find that under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

if you are using .net4

after running the wizard you should see some tables have been added to your database these are your membership tables

after running this you may need to check your connection string out and ensure that it is correct

if these are all correct

when running the membership you should be able to add users

Thanks Inkey